# C# microsoft excel 2003 move through sheets

Tags: c#, excel, ssis

I am working on a SSIS package C# script task and I am converting .xls file to .csv file, I encountered this problem that only one sheet is only written

```
string fileFullPath = "";

        //Get one Book(Excel file at a time)
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            string filename = "";
            fileFullPath = SourceFolderPath + "\\" + file.Name;
            filename = file.Name.Replace(".xls", "");
            //MessageBox.Show(fileFullPath);

            //Create Excel Connection
            string ConStr;
            string HDR;
            HDR = "YES";
            ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileFullPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=1\"";
            OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);
            bool isDouble;
            double dbl;


            //Get Sheet Name
            cnn.Open();
            DataTable dtSheet = cnn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            string sheetname;
            sheetname = "";
            foreach (DataRow drSheet in dtSheet.Rows)
            {
                if (drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("$"))
                {
                    sheetname = drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                    //Display Sheet Name , you can comment it out
                    // MessageBox.Show(sheetname);

                    //Load the DataTable with Sheet Data
                    OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("select * from [" + sheetname + "]", cnn);
                    //cnn.Open();
                    OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    adp.Fill(dt);

                    //drop $from sheet name
                    sheetname = sheetname.Replace("$", "");

                    //Create CSV File and load data to it from Sheet
                    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(DestinationFolderPath + "\\" + filename + "_" + sheetname + ".csv", false);
                    int ColumnCount = dt.Columns.Count;
                    string[] columnName = new string[ColumnCount];
                    // Write the Header Row to File
                    for (int i = 0; i < ColumnCount; i++)
                    {
                        sw.Write(dt.Columns[i]);
                        columnName[i] = dt.Columns[i].ToString();
                        if (i < ColumnCount - 1)
                        {
                            sw.Write(FileDelimited);
                        }
                    }
                    sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

                    // Write All Rows to the File
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < ColumnCount; i++)
                        {
                            if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
                            {
                                if (columnName[i] == "DATE_TIME")
                                {

                                    isDouble = Double.TryParse(dr[i].ToString(), out dbl);

                                    if (isDouble)
                                    {
                                        sw.Write(DateTime.FromOADate(dbl));
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());
                                }
                            }
                            if (i < ColumnCount - 1)
                            {
                                sw.Write(FileDelimited);
                            }
                        }
                        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
                    }
                    sw.Close();
                }
            }
            cnn.Close();
        }
```

The first sheet written successfuly but on the second iteration the sheetname does not change and I encoutnered this error `The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'surot$_'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.` on the line `adp.Fill(dt);` it still accessing the sheet `surot$` even it completed the creation of the csv file for the `surot$`

EDIT 1: When I check the rows count of `dtsheet` it contains `6` instead of `3` why does this happen? also tha naming becomes `surot$,surot$_` it seems like it duplicate the excel files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue.

check to see if last character is NOT an underscore "_" in your IF statement.

For some reason it always doubles like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the Schema as per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.getoledbschematable(v=vs.110).aspx) by specifying the 2nd argument in the parameter, like this:

```
DataTable dtSheet = cnn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables,
new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
```